# VBA converting formula to comment

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have a formula that uses an apostrophe "'" and therefore VBA reads it as a comment, is there anyway to prevent this?

formula is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$A$1:$A$10&"'!"&"$BI$1:$BI$1000"),C4,INDIRECT("'"&$A$1:$A$10&"'!"&"$ax$1:$ax$1000")))
```

have everything else working

Comment: You need to double up any quotation marks (not apostrophes) that are in the formula when you assign it in VBA. Eg `activecell.formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT(""'""&$A$1:$A$10&""'!""&""$BI$1:$BI$1000""),C4,INDIRECT(""'""&$A$1:$A$10&""'!""&""$ax$1:$ax$1000"")))"`

Comment: formulas in VBA start with double quotes `"=SUMPROUCT(...)" I don't know what are you trying here but the apostrophe can go inside the first string.

Comment: @Fergus Myles Please consider approving my answer if it helped or commenting if it didn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Chr(34)` in VBA and `CHAR(34)` in workbook formulas in place of `"`. Much more easier to use and not so hard to understand if it's the first time you see it.

```vb
my_quoted_string = "this part is not in quotes " & Chr(34) & "while this part is" & Chr(34)
```

Will return

```
this part is not in quotes "while this part is"
```

For apostrophes use `Chr(39)` and `CHAR(39)` instead.